# PHP 5.4: prevent headers from being set after output

Tags: php, header, outputstream

I am used to headers not being able to be sent after output has started. In fact, I count on it.

In the application I'm working on, after every succesful updating or inserting query, the page is reloaded with a `header('Location: ...')` call. That's because I don't want the page with the POST data to be refresh-able.

But while developing, one of these queries might just have a bug in them - and then I'm printing out some debug information (with `echo`). This would then prevent the page from being reloaded - but ever since I upgraded to php 5.4, it simply reloads anyway. I can only read the debug information if I `exit;` after printing the debug information - which I don't like, because some more debug information might follow later in the script.

If I check `headers_sent()` in one of those echo calls, it says headers have not been sent yet. So it looks like it's being buffered without me (knowingly) having turned that on.

It might of course be a php.ini setting rather than the mere fact I'm now using version 5.4, but I can't find it.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried `error_reporting(E_ALL)`?

Comment: What is the value of `output_buffering` in your `php.ini` file?

Comment: Thank you jeroen - it's silly, but I had looked over this value. output_buffering is indeed set (to 4096) which causes my debug information to be automatically kept in buffer, allowing the header to be set. It must have been off on my previous php installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jeroen answered my question (in a comment on my original question) by pointing me to the `output_buffering` setting in `php.ini`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use output buffering to solve this. Basically all you need to do is to call `ob_start();` as soon as you can. Then, instead of sending stuff out instantly, PHP would buffer the output. So it does not really matter what you set first, body or headers. They will be set in buffer, so manipulation is not a problem unless buffer is sent. If you do not flush buffer explicitly it will be sent by PHP when your script ends. See [Output Buffering Control](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) chapter in PHP manual.

Comment: I understand your suggestion, but I don't think that's what I want: I do NOT want buffering, but I seem to be getting it anyway. I do in fact want the `header()` call to fail due to the output having been started, so that I can see the debug information.

Comment: It was indeed an output buffering issue though - thanks to jeroen's comment on my original question, I was able to find that php was automatically buffering output due to output_buffering being set in php.ini.